# how do I fix fix the Identifier issue with this code?

Tags: java

```
public class Patients{
public String Patients;
public int IDNumber;


 Patients(IDNumber){
  this.IDNumber = IDNumber;
   for(int i = 0; IDNumber.length; i++){
  System.out.println("patient" + i);
  }
 }
}
```

-calls patients and IDNumber to give a patient an ID number. How do I fix the identifier error here?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide more context about what your code is supposed to do. It's unclear what the intent is as it contains at least three bugs (missing type for parameter in constructor, *IDNumber* is not an object and does not have any member variables like *length*, *length* is not a boolean variable and thus insufficient as the loop condition).

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `IDNumber` as an `int`, and `int`s in Java are not objects, and don't have attribute `length`. I'm not sure on what you want to do with your code, but try to go with:

```
for(int i = 0; i < IDNumber; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors in this code:

```
public class Patients{
public String Patients;
public int IDNumber;


 Patients(IDNumber){
  this.IDNumber = IDNumber;
   for(int i = 0; IDNumber.length; i++){
  System.out.println("patient" + i);
  }
 }
}
```

A lot of the following you probably won't understand (yet).

1. Readability concerns:

   - The indentation is a mess.
   - The whitespace usage is not conformant to style guides.

   OK, the compiler won't care, but other people reading your code will.  And if you don't care about readability and maintainability of your code, then you have probably chosen the wrong programming language to learn.

   From (just!) this perspective, the code should look like

   ```
   public class Patients {
       public String Patients;
       public int IDNumber;

       Patients(IDNumber) {
           this.IDNumber = IDNumber;
           for (int i = 0; IDNumber.length; i++) {
               System.out.println("patient" + i);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. `public String Patients;`

   - Field names should start with a lowercase letter.
   - A field that has the same name as the class is asking for trouble.
   - Fields should not be `public` because it leads to porous abstractions.  In most cases fields should be declared as `private`.
   - This particular field is not used in your code.
   - The field name `Patients` (or `patients`) is incorrect in the sense that it doesn't give any real idea what the `String` really represents.
3. `public int IDNumber;`

   - The field name and access modifier are incorrect; see 2.
   - The type of the field doesn't match how you are trying to use it; see 5.
4. `Patients(IDNumber){`

   - This should be `public` ... unless your intention is to hide the constructor.
   - Method and constructor parameter names should start with a lowercase letter.
   - The parameter declaration is missing the parameter type.
5. `for(int i = 0; IDNumber.length; i++){`

   - `IDNumber.length` needs to be a boolean expression
   - assuming that `IDNumber` is an `int`, `int` values don't have any fields, so `IDNumber.length` is invalid.
   - if `IDNumber` is supposed to be an "array of integers", that *does* have a `length` field, but then `IDNumber.length` will be an integer not a boolean.  Maybe you should be writing `i < IDNumber.length` there?
6. `System.out.println("patient" + i);`

   - It does not make sense to do this kind of thing *in a constructor*.  Do you really need to write stuff the console every time you *create* a `Patients` object?  Shouldn't this code (the loop!) be somewhere else?  Like in a print or `toString()` method?
7. `public class Patients{`

   - On reading and thinking about the code in its totality, it is *unclear* whether you intend a single instance of this class to represent one patient or a collection of patients.  In the former case that class name is *incorrect*.  In the latter case, the fields are *incorrect*.

---

This is the question you actually asked:

> -calls patients and IDNumber to give a patient an ID number.

The code you have shown us doesn't do (just) that.  It also seems to be trying to print stuff.

> How do I fix the identifier error here?

It is not clear *which specific identifier error* you are talking about, so it is hard to understand what you are specifically asking.

However, as you should have realized by now, the problems with this code cannot be resolved by simply "fixing an identifier error".  You need to start by *understanding* the problem that you have been given.  Start by figuring out what this `Patients` class is *actually* supposed to represent.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to call the "length" method on an int object.
Try changing it the argument in the for loop.

Comment: thank you fo your comment I tried this but I keep getting the Idetifier error

Comment: It is not an "int object".  Values of type `int` are not objects.  And `length` does not refer to a method.  It refers to a (non-existent) attribute of an (non-existent) object.  You don't help beginners if you use wildly inaccurate terminology ... or guesswork.

Comment: (And *"Try changing it the argument in the for loop"* doesn't even make sense as an English sentence.)